# Use getters and setters of a Kotlin Model class inside an Android Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm asking this question because I have lots of usages like this and I couldn't find a solution so far.

For an Android project, I'm using getters, and setters of a Java Model class inside my Activity in Java like this -

```
Model model = new Model();
model.setName("sonething");

Toast.makeText(this, model.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The problem is, when I change my Model class to Kotlin, I don't get getters and setters like this inside the Java Activity and I can access the model class field variable with just the name of the variable.

But I don't want to change anything in the Activity code above because I have lots of Activities like this. How can that be accomplished by making changes in the Kotlin model class?

My Model class in Kotlin looks like this -

```
class Model {
    var name : String? = null
    // set a value for name from Activity using the setter
}
```

Comment: Kotlin compiler will generate a getter and a setter for a property in order to make it interoperable with Java. Your Java code looks fine and I don't see why it would fail to compile.

Comment: Just as Egor said, the getters and setters are generated at automatically by kotlin. Are you getting any compile time error currently while using the kotlin model class?

Comment: You can also annotate your Kotlin properties with `@get:JvmName("customJavaGetterName")` and/or `@set:JvmName("customJavaSetterName")` if the generated getter and/or setter name don't match your old Java implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use apply, also, let, run etc. to accomplish what you are trying to achieve. To understand the difference, [here](https://proandroiddev.com/the-difference-between-kotlins-functions-let-apply-with-run-and-else-ca51a4c696b8) is a helpful blog writings

For instance:

```
val model = Model().apply{ name = "aveek"}

Toast.makeText(this, model.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: My Activity where I'm using the Model is in Java. Thats the whole issue. I cannot change my Activity code, there are many like that.

Comment: Then create methods inside Kotlin Model class like setName, getName !!

Comment: @Aveek No, you don't need to create these methods. As the comments say, they are already created by the compiler.

Comment: Hi @AlexeyRomanov, thanks for the reply. Basically, I thought as it is failing to compile just like Egor asked, I suggested that to have this in order for the code to compile. Of course that is not the correct solution. I also think, Gissipi_453 have some other issues or he misunderstood something inside.